# Connection exception using Spring JDBC Template

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a simple Web App developed using Spring and recently I'm having some problems with DB connections. My DB is on MS SQL Server 2005.

To retrieve data I implemented several DAO using JDBCTemplate class provided by the framework.

Sometimes I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: StatementCallback; SQL [SELECT [Campaigns].[CampaignID],[CampaignCode],[CampaignType],[StartDate],[EndDate],[Status],[FirstUpdate],[LastUpdate],[FirstUpdateUserID],[LastUpdateUserID],[CampaignDescriptions].[Description] FROM [Campaigns] INNER JOIN [CampaignDescriptions] ON [Campaigns].[CampaignID] = [CampaignDescriptions].[CampaignID] ORDER BY [StartDate] DESC]; Connection reset by peer: socket write error; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

the exception seems to occur only when the reported query is executed.

I can't understand what's causing this problem. Any idea?

The method executing the query is:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
public Campaign[] getAll() {
    List<Campaign> campList = getJdbcTemplate()
            .query(BASE_QUERY,
                    new CampaignMapper());
    return campList.toArray(new Campaign[0]);
}
```

where `BASE_QUERY` is the same in the exception message.

Comment: the pertinent part of the error is : "SQLServerException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error"

Comment: how do you declare datasourse in spring application config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it kinda of smells like a stale connection problem. It might be showing up only in this query if it is quite common or the first to be executed (most of the time).

Things to check:

- Server side connection timeout
- Connection pool minium idle timeout
- Connection pool verify connection before use

Comment: so it could be that the falling request is getting a stale connection from the pool. what connection pool are you using?

Comment: i'm using `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` as datasource for my dao. I'm not setting any pool parameter...

Comment: @davioooh add parameter validationQuery to your datasourse, like this: `<property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 as res"/>`

Comment: @user1516873 is there a way to also set connection timeout?

Comment: @davioooh i think you should create new question, not spoil this one.